# Unable to Access Sharepoint Library "files which have no checked in version"

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Previously I was able to navigate the "files which had no checked in version", however now I'm getting an error "exceeds the list view threshold" (see image below).

Is there a configuration that can be changed as to be able to access this list? The solutions that I find online (most of them suggest filtering) apply to libraries contents, but that does not apply to this one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the List **View** has exceeded the default 5,000 SharePoint item limit. (There are several tips to handle it [here](https://www.mrsharepoint.guru/resolve-the-sharepoint-item-limit-threshold/)).

**The key thing here is that you can't do *anything* until your View is under 5,000 items. That is why the only solution right now is filtering.**

- First, change the default view to filter out some items to get you under that 5,000 item limit. e.g. Filter on files Created Date and only show things that were created this year.

  - You need a view under 5,000 items *just* to do something.
- Try moving/deleting items to get under 5,000 or even start over with a new document library.
- If it is a document library, you can create subfolders and move data (remember each subfolder should have less than 5,000 items to keep you under the View limit)
- Use metadata to help filter/organize the library to keep within the limit.

Comment: This would work for most lists, however I need it specifically for the section "files which had no checked in version" which is not configurable as suggested in the link you shared.

Comment: The 5,000 item limit is a core SharePoint limitation, that doesn't just apply to views. It's easier to "work around" the limitation with filtering. So in this case, you can't apply any more filtering, so you still need to get the number of items under 5,000 first for it to start working again.